# What should I do to ssh with a key to a remote server from a Linux machine, when I can already ssh from a Windows machine using PuTTY?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, authentication, ssh-keys

From PuTTY, I can ssh log to a remote server since my public key has been "registered" to this server.
By now I can access this server through **only** this computer running PuTTY.

However I'd like to gain access from my laptop running *Linux Debian 9*.
How can I use key, the private one or the public one or both, to log to that server?
(without, if possible any configuration on the remote side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your key file to the Linux machine. Nothing needs to be done on the server-side (at least in general).

Note that PuTTY uses its own key format. If you are going to use OpenSSH client on the Linux machine, you will also need to convert your key to the OpenSSH format. You can do that with PuTTYgen tool on your Windows machine.

If you already have another key on the Linux machine (and you need it for something), make sure you do not overwrite it with the new (converted) key. The key files do not have to have specific names or locations. You can have as many of them as you need.

Comment: It took me some times to understand and then doing it, but what you suggested works fine! Thanks :)